# Dynamically want to upload image in cardview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

So basically I have attached my addimage.java code and mainpage.xml code below. whenever the user will click on addimage button he can  select image and   dynamically add images in my mainpage.xml file. So basically its like I want to transfer I image from activity to activity on a button click.
I tried doing that still I am stuck up a this specific point, where the user can selects image from gallery but still I don't know how will it get uploaded to mainpage.xml file.

Any help is highly appreciable.

this is my addimage.java code

```
public class addimage extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView imageView;
    private Button addimage;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    android.content.Intent data;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addimage);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        addimage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addimage);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);




        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 1);
            }
        });


        addimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (imageView != null) {
                    /*uploadToFirebase(imageView);*/
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PLEASE SELECT IMAGE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
           /* super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);*/
            switch (requestCode) {
                case 2://2 is from startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 2);
                    try {
                        Uri selectedImage = data.getData(); //get photo uri
                        imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }



    }
}
```

this is my mainpage.xml code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainpage"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".mainpage">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/Pink"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="950dp"
                android:layout_height="550dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:alpha="0.5"
                android:background="@color/purple_200"
                android:text="     BEGINNERS CALLIGRAPHY"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/DarkBlue"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <Button
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="210dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                android:text="PHOTOS"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:textColor="@color/purple_700"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="52dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                android:text="VIDEOS"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:textColor="@color/purple_700"/>


        </RelativeLayout>


        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="949dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:rowCount="3">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:background="@color/Purple">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="149dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageview_image"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:layout_row="0"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b1" />



                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView/>


            <!-- Row 2 -->

            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="149dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageview_image2"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b3" />



                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <!-- Column 2 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="149dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageview_image3"
                        android:layout_width="190dp"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b4" />



                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


            <!-- Row 2 -->

            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="149dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageview_image4"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b5" />



                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

           
        </GridLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/expanded_image"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="900dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <!--android:layout_gravity="center"-->




    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

If more code is required please comment below.

Comment: do you want to choose the image from gallery and show  it to the ImageView?

Comment: Yes.... Can u help me how can I achieve that

Comment: 2.After showing image in imageview I want it to get uploaded to xml page dynamically...

Comment: where  add my code? could update your code after change.

Answer (score 0):

try to add code to this addimage class:

```
public class addimage extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView imageView;
private Button addimage;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
android.content.Intent data;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addimage);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    addimage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addimage);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
            galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 1);
        }
    });
    
    addimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (imageView != null) {
                /*uploadToFirebase(imageView);*/
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PLEASE SELECT IMAGE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1://1 is from startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 2);
            try {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData(); //get photo uri
                imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what's the error? did  get the storage permission?@Suzzi

Comment: error: ';' expected protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { ^

Comment: Where add my code? It seems to be a syntax error. You can update the code.@Suzzi

Comment: Yes wait I will update...I updated the  code

Comment: you put onActivityResult in a wrong place, i update the whole code @Suzzi

Comment: requestCode should be the same 1 .   @Suzzi

Comment: yes , switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:// change to 1